# Как сохранить значение словаря в файле с именем как у словаря ? Python

Tags: python, файлы

Хочу сохранить в файл содержимое словарей. Если использовать функцию как на примере, то как мне из передаваемого параметра (содержимое словаря) получить имя параметра для создания такого же файла ?

```
def save_dict_2_file(dict):
    with open("my_dict",'w') as f: # здесь нужно указать имя файла "my_dict"
        pprint(dict, f) 

my_dict = {'A':[1,2,3,4,5]}
save_dict_2_file(my_dict)
```

Решение - через EVAL

```
 def save_dict_2_file(dict_name): 
        with open(dict_name,'w') as f:
            pprint(eval(dict_name), f)


my_dict = {'A':[1,2,3,4,5]}
save_dict_2_file('my_dict')
```

Картинка- сформированы 3 разных по названию и размерам файла - дампы справочников.
[image: Картинка- сформированы 3 разных по названию и размерам файла - дампы справочников.]

Comment: а для чего это нужно?

Comment: есть  многоуровневые словари, несколько - справочники, распарсеный лог и т.д. Где-то что-то не клеится, хочу полазить по структуре.. для отладки нужно. Ну а имена под названия словарей чтобы не запутаться.

Comment: как-то все равно не понятно. имена-то у ваших словарей откуда берутся? я так понимаю, вы хотите присвоить файлу имя такое же, как имя переменной, содержащей словарь?

Comment: вот в этом и вопрос - как определить имя файла ?

Comment: Твое решение СЛУЧАЙНО работает, потому что ты в функцию передаешь такой же текст (который потом и является именем файла), как называется словарь. Измени что-нибудь из этого и работать перестанет.

Comment: Пример привел на картинке в вопросе, мое решение рабочее :-)

Comment: приведенный код не может создать три файла с разными именами, потому что он создает файл с именем ``my_dict``

Comment: да, я 3 раза вызывал функцию с разными параметрами. Мне нужно было сделать дамп в файл для каждого словаря

Comment: И как вызов функции с разными параметрами решает задачу "из передаваемого параметра (содержимое словаря) получить имя параметра"?  Это обычно создание файла с нужным именем вручную. Какой в этом вообще смысл? Для 100 словарей писать 100 разных строчек?

Comment: В ходе решения, приведенного выше в Вопросе, передается уже ИМЯ, из которого с помощью eval берется СОДЕРЖИМОЕ. Да, для каждого словаря я пишу вызов функции. Мне больше нравится через функцию а не через правку в коде.  self.save_dict_2_file('self.dict_svod')/self.save_dict_2_file('self.dict_itf_spr')/self.save_dict_2_file('self.dict_itf_data')

Comment: Т.е. в итоге, решение задачи "из передаваемого параметра (содержимое словаря) получить имя параметра" совсем не интересовало? Зачем тогда надо было создавать вопрос, если изначально было ясно, что для каждого словаря можно написать свою строчку и все будет сделано 

Comment: Если вы внимательно посмотрите на вопрос - то в первой части его именно словарь передавался в функцию и необходимо было в ней выяснить имя. Затем я нашел решение с eval, но при этом нужно передавать имя словаря. Мне нужна была функция, считайте прихотью.

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_dict_2_file(dict):
    name = [k for k, v in globals().items() if v == dict][0]
```

После выполнения

```
my_dict33 = {'A':[1,2,3,4,5]}

save_dict_2_file(my_dict33)
```

в `name` будет строка "`my_dict33`", т.е. имя переданной переменной.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но у меня выдает ошибку. IndexError: list index out of range. В перечислении значений K нет "dict" (я развернул ваш ответ в несколько строк)

Comment: что значит "развернул в несколько строк"?

Comment: ну что-то в вроде for k, v in globals().items()\n print(k,v)

Comment: Так там и не должно быть dict, там должно быть имя переменной, которая в функцию передается. Ведь именно это требуется. Если вызвать функцию как ``save_dict_2_file(my_dict)``, то там будет ``my_dict``, что будет присвоено переменной ``name``, которую потом можно передать в ``open(name)`` как имя файла